# Genetic algorithm for workstation assignments

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

**Background**

I have a project where I need to assign roughly 200 full time employees (FTEs) to their workstations. FTEs have the following properties:

- ID (numeric string)
- Level (Admins, Seniors, Mid-Level, Juniors, Associates)
- Manager ID
- Workstation Type (office, premium, new, average, old) (in descending order of quality).
- Department

All FTEs have been assigned a type of workstation based on their level, so Admin-levels are more likely to get office types. Mid-Levels are likely to get new types, but if there aren't enough, they might get bumped up to a premium if there are spares. There will likely be empty workstations after everyone is assigned.

Workstations are also divided into separate sections, numbered 0-9. Each section has a different number of workstations.

**Objective**

Assignments are done with the following priorities (highest first):

1. FTEs in the Marketing department must sit in Section 2. In case there are not enough workstations there, they can "overflow" to an adjacent section.
2. Group members (those who share the same manager) must be within 5 workstation units of each other.
3. Managers must be within 10 units of the closest group member.
4. Those in the same department must be within 5 units of each other.

Distances between one workstation to another are represented as a weighted graph data structure. Each vertex is a workstation and each edge has the distance to its neighboring workstations.

What is the best way to encode this problem for a genetic algorithm, and what would be suitable choices for crossover, mutation, and fitness functions?

I currently have an algorithm using OX1 crossover and random swapping, but in general it performs poorly and slowly. The chromosome is encoded as an array of objects representing FTEs, but since I'm green to all this, that probably isn't the best way to do things.

Comment: What is the input for this? Do you have a list of people at the beginning of the day and then do one big assignment or do the people come one by one into the office and need to be assigned to a single desk each?

Comment: @fafl I have a list of FTEs and would do one assignment, yes. Right now it's in a spreadsheet with their names and properties in separate columns, but depending on what the encoding is, I could potentially transform it into JSON or something.

Comment: If you have an implementation already, you have a fitness function as well. I'd propose to discuss it, because the fitness function is very important for a GA.